# Poor performance on IIS7, only on Windows Server 2008, fine on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I'm new to IIS7 but have experience with other versions.

I've been working on an application that works great in a dev environment (as always) but when I push it to a windows server 2008/IIS7 box performance takes a noticeable hit.

The dev environment is Windows7/IIS7. The configuration in IIS is the same on the dev box as the server. I've tried all sorts of things to try and find a reason for this but I cant come to any conclusion. I've ruled out database problems on the live box as all data is cached after the first request. I've confirmed this to be true and made sure there is no additional database traffic.

I've ruled out network issues with a combination of monitoring requests with fiddler and local debugging on the server. Whenever the code runs on the server there seems to be a performance issue.

The server:

Intel Core 2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.40ghz with 2gb RAM. I know this is not fantastic but I was expecting it to at least perform as well as my dev environment (which is running much more on a lower spec).

The CPU using peaks at under 60%, and memory usage is less than half of the available.

I've enabled failed request tracing and most of the time is spent in a custom HttpModule, this module works to handle every request, I cant get any more detail as to what within the module may be causing the problem.

Any ideas, I've been pulling my hair out for days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please do verify that you don't have any of Custom Modules in debug build. Dev box may not show such performance issue as they may not have enough traffic as seen on Production servers.

Also, make sure there are no debug="true" in the web.config files in your application.

Performance Monitor can also give you good information on what may be causing high CPU issue. 

Check this out [High memory, CPU, or other performance problems with .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2007/11/26/high-memory-cpu-or-other-performance-problems-with-net.aspx)